# Build and compile Samsung Glalaxy S 3 mini

Tags: android, flush, android-build, rom

I need to get Android source Code in linux platform to build and compile my own ROM, like this example [Building the System](http://source.android.com/source/building.html).

but I found that Galaxy S 3 mini NOT listed for building devices  [Building for devices](http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html).

So we can build and compile JUST the listed devices from previous link ??

Answer (score 0):

The Android Open Source Project (AOSP for short) only support Google endorsed phones. That is mainly the **Nexus** line.

As stated on the [Building for devices](http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html) page, you will also need proprietary binary drivers to build a working system. Again, only the Nexus devices drivers are available from Google.

As such, building a custom ROM from AOSP for non-Nexus device *may* require significant work. You should search for existing custom ROMs for your device. Maybe you can get help from there

Comment: i need to add wireless package for my android device like this link , but do i need new source android with linux platform to do that ??? http://www.onlyxool.net/porting-iw-tools-to-android/